# Powershell Finding the most recent entry in csv that matches criteria

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a large CSV going back 10 months of every PC's login. Thousands of entries.

example of CSV file setup

```
hostname,room,ip,date,time,user,text,domain
PC45556,4,192.168.0.5,01/01/2020,00:51:20,Bob,Audited,WorkDomain
PC67978,2,192.168.0.45,01/01/2020,05:27:40,Dave,Audited,WorkDomain
PC45556,3,192.168.0.85,01/01/2020,05:30:19,Bob,Audited,WorkDomain
PC97799,4,192.168.0.55,01/01/2020,05:35:31,Sue,Audited,WorkDomain
```

I need to find the most recent entry for a given hostname and output the IP address. The PCs will have been logged into multiple times a day.

Comment: Given the "Uk" in your name: are these day-first or month-first date strings? Please update your question directly rather than replying in a comment. Also, it would help if you showed what you've tried so far and where, specifically, you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to get the last value

```
 Import-Csv .\file.csv |  Group-Object hostname | Foreach { $_.Group | Select -Last 1 } | select hostname, ip
```

result

```
hostname ip
-------- --
PC45556  192.168.0.85
PC67978  192.168.0.45
PC97799  192.168.0.55
```

also ask for specific values

```
 Import-Csv .\file.csv | where user -EQ Bob
```

or

```
 Import-Csv .\file.csv | where room -EQ 4
```

if entries are not sorted in csv use Sort

```
| Sort date
```

example:

```
  Import-Csv .\file.csv |  Group-Object hostname | Foreach { $_.Group | Sort date,time | Select -Last 1 } | select hostname, ip
```

ForEach-> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object?view=powershell-7

Select -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String?view=powershell-7

Group-Object https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Group-Object?view=powershell-7

Import-Csv -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Import-Csv?view=powershell-7

Sort -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 0):

Because your example doesn't show what the exact date format is (could be either 'dd/MM/yyyy' or 'MM/dd/yyyy'), you might have to change the `$dateFormat` variable in below code.

The idea is to sort the records in the csv on the combined properties for `date` and `time` so you can actually do a correct sorting on DateTime objects.

```
# change this to 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss' if the month comes first in your csv
$dateFormat = 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' 

$result = Import-Csv -Path 'Path\To\TheFile.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $newest = $_.Group | 
              Sort-Object @{Expression = {[datetime]::ParseExact(('{0} {1}' -f $_.date, $_.time), $dateFormat, $null)}} | 
              Select-Object -Last 1
    [PsCustomObject] @{hostname = $_.Name; ip = $newest.ip }
}

# output on screen
$result

# write to new CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\hostnames.csv'
```

Using your example, the output is

```
hostname ip          
-------- --          
PC45556  192.168.0.85
PC67978  192.168.0.45
PC97799  192.168.0.55
```